# Facing Issues with RabbitMQ while deploying Taiga in linux environment

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, ubuntu-22.04, taiga

I am setting up taiga in a Hyper-V Ubuntu 22.04 as a test project. I have successfully installed all the modules but for some unknown reason RabbitMQ isnt working properly at taiga events. Whenever I try to hit the server it shows "Update Required". So I have updated the rabbitMQ to the latest version. And its showing that its working properly. But it still showing  "Update Required".

taiga event env config:

```
RABBITMQ_URL="amqp://rabbitmquser:rabbitmqpassword@rabbitmqhost:5672/taiga"
WEB_SOCKET_SERVER_PORT=8888
APP_PORT=3023
SECRET="TaigaSecretKey"
ALGORITHM="HS256"
AUDIENCE=
ISSUER=
USER_ID_CLAIM="user_id"
# Valid log level values: error, warn, info, http, verbose, debug, silly
LOG_LEVEL="info"
```

```
Nginx Config:
 server {

    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name localhost;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}



server {

    listen 443 default_server;

    server_name localhost;  #  See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html



    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    charset utf-8;



    access_log /home/taiga/logs/nginx.access.log;

    error_log /home/taiga/logs/nginx.error.log;



    # TLS: Configure your TLS following the best practices inside your company

    # Other configurations



    # Frontend

    location / {

        alias /home/taiga/taiga-front-dist/dist/;

        index index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;

    }



    # API

    location /api/ {

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/api/;

        proxy_redirect off;

    }



    # Admin

    location /admin/ {

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/admin/;

        proxy_redirect off;

    }



    # Static files

    location /static/ {

        alias /home/taiga/taiga-back/static/;

    }



    # Media

    location /_protected/ {

        internal;

        alias /home/taiga/taiga-back/media/;

        add_header Content-disposition "attachment";

    }



    # Unprotected section

    location /media/exports/ {

        alias /home/taiga/taiga-back/media/exports/;

        add_header Content-disposition "attachment";

    }



    location /media/ {

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8003/;

        proxy_redirect off;

    }



    # Events

    location /events {

        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_connect_timeout 7d;

        proxy_send_timeout 7d;

        proxy_read_timeout 7d;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/events;

    }

}
```

My question is what's I am missing actually? I have gone through the documentations for several times. but didn't find any results. Any help would be appreciated.
steps I have tried:

1. reinstalling RabbitMQ and Erlang
2. Trying different ports in config files and env files